# Xampp Virtualhost: Wildcard domains and sub-domains

Tags: apache, xampp, wildcard, virtualhost, wildcard-subdomain

I read through the other post but none seemed to answer the question i have been having. Is it possible to have wildcard Subdomains of wildcard Domains (even if its just for subdomains and not sub-subdomains) like: foo.example.local.
I already have example.local working but i can't figure out how to get foo.example.local to grab the files from the folder /sub/foo within the /example folder. 
My config at this moment (httpd-vhost.conf):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
</VirtualHost>
<Virtualhost *:80>
VirtualDocumentRoot "C:/xampp/www/%-2"
    ServerName domain.local
    ServerAlias *.local
    <Directory "C:/xampp/www/*">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
         Require all granted
     </Directory>
</Virtualhost>
<Virtualhost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "C:/xampp/www/%-2/sub/%-3"
    ServerName sub.domain.local
    ServerAlias *.*.local
    <Directory "C:/xampp/www/*/sub/*">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted     
    </Directory>
</Virtualhost>
```

What currently happens is that the foo.example.local simply goes to the example folder and not to the example/sub/foo folder which is what i want it to do.

Oh and i have already enabled: `LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so` within httpd.conf

Host file contains both lines:

- 127.0.0.1    example.local
- 127.0.0.1    foo.example.local

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out, to add sub-domain functionality both through wildcards i just had to use a second asterisk before in the *.domain.local to * . *.local
So the final result will be as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
</VirtualHost>
<Virtualhost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "C:/xampp/www/%-2/sub/%-3"
    ServerName sub.domain.local
    ServerAlias *.*.local
    <Directory "C:/xampp/www/*/sub/*">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted     
    </Directory>
</Virtualhost>
<Virtualhost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "C:/xampp/www/%-2"
    ServerName domain.local
    ServerAlias *.local
    <Directory "C:/xampp/www/*">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</Virtualhost>
```

And the important part is this:

```
VirtualDocumentRoot "C:/xampp/www/%-2/sub/%-3"
ServerName sub.domain.local
ServerAlias *.*.local
<Directory "C:/xampp/www/*/sub/*">
```

Simple fix making it easy to create Sub domains within the same folder as the main domain. Allowing you to easily create multiple domains within one single project folder.

Answer (score 1):

### XAMPP 7.3.7 (INFINITE *.LOCALHOST) + SOME SYMFONY v4 DOMAINS

Edit and activate the Apache "vhost alias module" (Uncomment the #)

FILE=C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf

```
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
```

FILE=C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

Edit with this, works OK with Chrome (Not Firefox)

```
#############################
## LOCALHOST
#############################
<VirtualHost *:80>
       UseCanonicalName Off
       DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
       ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>


#############################
## SYMFONY VHOSTS (/public)
#############################

<VirtualHost *:80>
       UseCanonicalName Off       
       DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/symfonyapi/public/"
       ServerName symfonyapi.localhost

        <Directory C:/xampp/htdocs/symfonyapi/public/>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>       

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
       UseCanonicalName Off       
       DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/symfonyweb/public/"
       ServerName symfonyweb.localhost

        <Directory C:/xampp/htdocs/symfonyweb/public/>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>


#############################
## VHOSTS *.LOCALHOST
#############################
<VirtualHost *:80>
       UseCanonicalName Off
       ServerAlias *.localhost
       VirtualDocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/%1/"
</VirtualHost>
```

For HTTPS

FILE=C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

#   General setup for the virtual host
# DocumentRoot "/xampp/htdocs"
# ServerName www.example.com:443
# ServerAdmin admin@example.com
# ErrorLog "/xampp/apache/logs/error.log"
# TransferLog "/xampp/apache/logs/access.log"

UseCanonicalName Off
ServerAlias *.localhost
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
VirtualDocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs/%1"
ErrorLog "/xampp/apache/logs/%1.error.log"
TransferLog "/xampp/apache/logs/%1.access.log"
```

Create domains:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\dev1
C:\xampp\htdocs\dev2
C:\xampp\htdocs\dev3
```